# Centering a logo on top of homepage

Tags: html, padding

I'm fairly new at coding, i'm learning html and i was given an assignment with the requirement of having the logo on top of the home page and centered with 10% padding.

I've never done this before so i'd appreciate the help very much

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let me to try answer your quetion my friend.
Maybe i have two way to answer your question.

1. I assume that is a navbar.

```css
.navbar{
background-color: #878f99;
padding: 6px 8px;
display:flex;
justify-content:flex-start;
align-items:center;
}
.logo{
width:20px;
height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="navbar">
<img alt="" src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/google-logo-png/google-logo-png-suite-everything-you-need-know-about-google-newest-0.png" class="logo" />
</div>
</div>
```

2. Just make for top position

```css
.page{
diplay:flex;
}
.logo{
width:30px;
height:30px;
bottom:50%
right:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<img alt="" src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/google-logo-png/google-logo-png-suite-everything-you-need-know-about-google-newest-0.png" class="logo" />
</div>
```

or you can like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.a {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

div.b {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
} 

div.c {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  border: 3px solid green;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The top Property</h1>

<div class="a">This div element has position: relative;
  <div class="b">This div element has position: absolute and top: -20px.</div>
</div>

<div class="c">This div element has no parent element, has position: absolute and is placed 150 pixels down from the top of the document body.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

3. ...

```css
.page{
display:flex;
align-items:flex-start;
justify-content:center;
padding-top:10px;
}
.logo{
width:20px;
height:20px
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <img alt="" src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/google-logo-png/google-logo-png-suite-everything-you-need-know-about-google-newest-0.png" class="logo" />
    </div>
```

sorry for my false if i false

Comment: You should use justify-content: center; rather than flex-start. He wants the logo to be centered.

Comment: yeah it's true. it can be. Thanks brother

Comment: i have been editted it